# how to display the icon right side & Top position on navigation bar using bootswrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Am trying to display the **arrow** icon right side for navigation bar, now it is looking like below

[image: my screen shot]

But needs to show like in below screen

[image: Expected Screen]

```
<div id="sidebar-wrapper">
  <ul class="sidebar-nav">
    <li class="sidebar-brand"><a href="#">Start Bootstrap </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><span style="float:right" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"> </span></a> 
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a> 
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a> 
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Please let me know how to set exactly like in screen shot.

Comment: Not sure what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: write clean code or try to make fiddle, till your requirement is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```css
 .sidebar-nav li{
  background: #000000; 
  line-height: 40px; 
  list-style: outside none none; 
  position: relative;
  border-bottom:1px solid #333;
 }
 .sidebar-nav li a { 
  color: #ffffff; 
  padding: 0 10px; 
  text-decoration: none;
  position:relative;
 }
 span.arrow { 
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #000;
  padding: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  margin-top: 6px;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6" id="sidebar-wrapper">
 <ul class="sidebar-nav">
  <li class="sidebar-brand"><a href="#">Start Bootstrap </a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left arrow"></span></a> </li>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a> </li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a> </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```